# Red error Lines below firebaseListadapter Parameters

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting some red error lines in the parameter of `FirebaseListAdapter`. I tried with `FirebaseListOptions` but that didn,t work. 
Here's My code:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this,
            String.class,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            databaseReference
    ) {
```

I have the updated dependencies, Imported firebase ui , and everything that was required.

[Here is the Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFZJt.png)
[Screen shot with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTM4v.png)

Comment: What's the error message for those lines?

Comment: @DougStevenson It says FirebaseListAdapter() in FirebaseListAdapter cannot be applied to: and then show my parameters.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edidted the question and added the screen shot with the error message. Please check.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thank you for response. I read your comment earlier before asking but this didn't help me. My applications terminates when I use `Firebaselistoptions`