# Display Record From firebase in listview

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

This may be a bit long, but please help.
I want to display records from firebase in `listview` and I am using `childeventlistener` for that. **what I want is, when i Click on display button, It should display all the record in `listview`** but it doesn't display anything. I have another button to add record into the database, When I add record and then try to display data from base, it display the correct data. Here's my code

```
 final Intent intent = getIntent();
    str1 = intent.getStringExtra("ClassName");

    p = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
    String url = "https://onlookers-201096.firebaseio.com/" + str1;
    mRef = new Firebase(url);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.lv11);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, id);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    presentStudent = new LinkedHashSet<>();

     databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
              key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
              id.add(key + ":" + value);
              arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }

          @Override
          public void onChildChanged(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onChildRemoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onChildMoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });
```

What I can make out is it displays data only when a child is added. I want to display the data directly from the fire base as it is.
Note: I tried using firebase listadapter but still was unable to get any solution [Here is the question I asked earlier about FirebaseListadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930337/red-error-lines-below-firebaselistadapter-parameters)

[Here is my database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGdxY.png)
CSE is the child and it depends on user to choose this. If user enters CIVIL or MECHANICAL, it will create a new child with the respective name.

```
str1 = intent.getStringExtra("ClassName");
    String url = "https://onlookers-201096.firebaseio.com/" + str1;
    mRef = new Firebase(url);
```

I am using this link where `str1` has the name of the child to be appended

Comment: regarding firebaselistadapter error, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243957/firebase-list-adapter-constructor-error

Comment: Than you. But I have done all research before asking here. When I am trying `Firebaselistoptions` my application terminates.

Comment: If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.